# Visual corruption in terminal-emacs

Tags: terminal-emacs, unicode

I run Emacs in my terminal, which is primarily [kitty](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/) on macOS, but I'm experiencing the same (what I'm about to describe) with other terminal emulators:

In my shell `LANG` is `en_US.UTF-8` and I have fonts installed so that pretty much any unicode point can be displayed, e.g. [Symbols for Legacy Computing](https://codepoints.net/symbols_for_legacy_computing).

If a text file (C source code or whatever) contains such symbols and I open it in Emacs and scroll up and down, the buffer gets visibly "corrupted". It's especially noticeable with vertical splits, where  the corruption involves visual spill over between the buffers. It's a purely visual thing, the file on disk is not affected.

Other CLI and TUI programs don't seem to have that problem: `nano`, `vim`, `cat`'ing the file to `less`. Is there something I can do to fix the problem in Emacs, or is it a known limitation/bug?

Example file: [abi/constants.nim](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/michaelsbradleyjr/nim-notcurses/wrap_more/notcurses/abi/constants.nim), scroll to the end.

[image: visual corruption in Emacs]

If I run Emacs bare, it's not as severe but the problem is still evident

[image: visual corruption in Emacs bare]

I'm running macOS 13.3, kitty 0.27.1, Emacs 28.2. `TERM` is `xterm-kitty`.

With that setup I've also tried iTerm2 3.5.0-beta10, Terminal.app 2.13, WezTerm 20230326-111934-3666303c (`TERM` is `xterm-256color` for those) — I experience the same problem, so it doesn't seem to be terminal-specific.

From searching commits: kitty supports Unicode 15, iTerm2 supports at least Unicode 13 and likely newer, WezTerm supports Unicode 15. Terminal.app (ships with macOS) is not open source, but symbols added in Unicode 13 are displayed correctly.

I've also tried with the Emacs GUI (28.2, downloaded from emacsformacosx.com) and experience a similar problem.

[image]

Running the GUI bare doesn't make a difference.

[image]

Comment: You should search for duplicates; there are a few common issues in terminals. Your TERM variable might be set wrong, Emacs and Kitty might disagree about whether a character (or set of characters) count as double width or not, etc, etc.

Comment: And you should add a screenshot, and record which versions of Emacs and Kitty you are using, and which versions of Unicode they claim to support.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @db48x.  I don't often post to stack exchange (overflow, et al.). Do you think I should follow up on your advice by editing my question, or via comments on it?

Comment: By editing the question. Assume that the comments could be deleted, and strive for a question that others in your situation could find useful.

Comment: I have scrolled over the file you have linked. No problems. Fast scrolling clear glyphs. No sign of any corruption. Emacs 29.0.60 lucid (uses X), Linux Mint 21 Cinnamon.

Comment: I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your terminals just aren’t rendering those characters at the same width that Emacs expects them to be rendered. Emacs expects some of those characters to take up two character cells, but your terminal is rendering them in one.

Emacs stores this information in a variable called `char-width-table`. You can query the width that Emacs expects using the function `char-table-range.

For example, you can check the expected width of one of the angle block characters like this:

```lisp
(char-table-range char-width-table ?\U0001fb42)
```

For me this returns 2, but your terminal rendered that character inside a single cell. (You can find out what character is at point using `C-x =`.)

You could improve the display by carefully setting values in `char-width-table` using `(setf (char-table-range char-width-table ?\U0001FB42) 1)` and similar instructions (use `C-h f` to see the help for `char-table-range` for more information about specifying larger ranges in one go).

Or you could use the Emacs GUI, which will use the exact pixel widths of the characters as reported by the font used to display them, and avoid all this nonsense. This is my recommendation; there is a lot that Emacs cannot do when stuck inside of a terminal.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth answer. A user of Emacs on Linux commented on my question earlier and noted he doesn't experience the problem I reported. I'm not sure what setup you're running, but maybe you and he make for two reports that it's not a problem experienced on Linux / not-maOS (small data set, to be sure). Given I've tried in several terminals compiled from totally different codebases, do you think there could be a bug in the stdlib that's used by my compiler, e.g. buggy `wcwidth` in Apple's Xode clang? I'll continue to research the problem per your recommendations.

Comment: The exact same problem exists with most terminal emulators, regardless of OS. Not all of them use `wcwidth`. I don’t think that Emacs uses `wcwidth` at all. Either update `char-width-table` so that it is correct for your terminal, or use the GUI.

Comment: See the screenshots re: the Emacs GUI I added to to the bottom of my question. The problem doesn't manifest in quite the same way visually, but seems related.

Comment: The following elisp code fixes the display problem in my terminal:

`(set-char-table-range char-width-table '(#x1fb00 . #x1fbf9) 1)`

It does not resolve the display problem in the Emacs GUI. However, I use the GUI so rarely I'm not presently concerned about it.

Comment: The `char-width-table` is not used by the GUI, as I already told you. The GUI simply couldn’t find a font with the correct glyphs, which means changing your font settings may help. Be aware that you may not even _have_ fonts with these glyphs in them; it is very common for terminals to draw them without the aid of fonts.

Comment: Yes, I didn't fully appreciate what you noted about the GUI and `char-width-table`, but I get it now. Regarding terminal Emacs, before I installed Noto Sans Symbols and Symbol2, I was seeing empty boxes for a number of glyphs, but installing those fonts resolved that problem, and that was a couple of days before I posted my question here. I'm experimenting now with `set-fontset-font`, et al. (for the GUI) but so far not much luck. If I get stuck, I'll post a new question focused on that, but for now I'll keep looking through existing Q&A and web search results.